# Available height and width for a web component?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I am writing a web component for which I need to know the available height and width when a user drops it on their web page. The web component wraps everything in a Shadow DOM and includes potentially scrollable part at least in the height direction. Beside that it includes things like `<details><summary>...`.

I am trying to find a strategy for this. "Available height and width" may not be very well defined in this scenario.

Any suggestion for what I can use? Any suggestion for clarifying my question?

Comment: I’m pretty sure what you’re wanting is container queries. They don’t actually exist yet. Otherwise you’re going to be doing a lot of JavaScript

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks, yes, that is probably what I want. But even with such queries the problem is surprisingly complex. I am thinking of different ways to give the user some simple hints about this (since I do not expect them to understand the complexity). One way would be to add a `data-height-hint=*` for the user and take action from the user supplied value. But I am not sure.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @evolutionxbox The main problem in this particular case is keeping a (possibly scrollable) text visible. This arises because of an image/video also needs to be (possibly) visible. The number of top level child elements in in the web component this case is not so big so I can probably handle the complexity in JavaScript without very much difficulty, but still the interface to the surrounding HTML elements is not easy to grasp.

Comment: I’m having difficulty imagining what you mean. Would you mind adding a [mcve] to the question? One which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just imagine a web component with two top level element childs. One is an image. The other is a `<details>` element (with possibly a a big amount of contents).

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but your description is quite confusing to be honest. If you do not provide an image or a coding example it will be hard for people to help.

That being said, I have a feeling you are trying to solve a problem that should not be done by the web-components implementation and should rather be solved by the user. For instance, if you need the component to have a minimum height in order to display the image and the details then give it a `min-height` (which is maybe set dynamically based on data) and it should be up to the user to use it correctly (i.e. put in a place that has enough space).

Or if you would like the component to somehow be responsive, I think you could maybe use the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) API which would allow you to observe changes to the components width and height. Note that it is currently not available in Safari or IE. If you need to support those it would need a polyfill like **[this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill)**.

Comment: Thanks, in a comment above I wrote "Just imagine a web component with two top level element childs. One is an image. The other is a <details> element (with possibly a a big amount of contents). "

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. Yes, I am using ResizeObserver. (I am only interested in newer browsers.) The tricky part is that the content in <details> is not known. I have choosen to give the web component a max-height:100vh. This should probably make it easy for both the author using my web component and the user viewing the web page.